# groupCount() in java.util.regex.Matcher always returns 0

Tags: java, regex

I've trying to count how many matching patterns are there in a string. I'm new to using java.util.regex and I was planning on using matcher.groupCount() to get the number of matching groups. Since according to the documentation it returns the number of capturing groups.

> Returns the number of capturing groups in this matcher's pattern.
>
> Group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention. It is not
>   included in this count.
>
> Any non-negative integer smaller than or equal to the value returned
>   by this method is guaranteed to be a valid group index for this
>   matcher.

Here's a simplified example of my problem:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("@#@#@#@#@");
System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
```

Its output is 0. Which part did I misunderstand? How do I count the number of matching patterns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java RegEx Matcher.groupCount returns 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413974/java-regex-matcher-groupcount-returns-0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `groupCount` returns the number of groups in the `Pattern`.

Groups in a `Pattern` are parenthesis-delimited.

Your `Pattern` contains no groups.

If you are looking for the number of matches, use a `while` loop over the `Matcher`'s `find()` method (which returns `boolean`).

For instance:

```
int myMatches = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    myMatches++;
}
```

**Edit**

Java 7+'s named groups are *also* parenthesis-delimited, although they follow a slightly more complex syntax than unnamed groups.

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified any capturing groups. If you change your pattern like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(@)");
```

then you'll have a capturing group - but it will still only return 1, as each match only has a single group. `find()` will return `true` 5 times though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use paranthesis `()` in your regex for grouping. Refer [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for detailed explaination.

In your case `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@");` will just create default group with entire pattern. Hence you get the output as 0.

Try this instead:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(@)");
```

> I've trying to count how many matching patterns are there in a string

I think you want to determine the number of patterns found in the string. Unfortunately, grouping is not used for counting the number of matches.

You need to do something like this:

```
    int totalMatches = 0;
    while(matcher.find()) {
        // Number of pattern matches found in the String
        totalMatches++;
    }
```