# Why does a flag in a capture group remove the group?

Tags: java, regex

In the following code, `(?i:hot)` is a capture group. Or at least it should be... it matches the expression and consumes the characters.

However when I try to get the group count, it returns 0.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i:hot)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("hot diggity dog");
while (matcher.find()) {
    int groupCount = matcher.groupCount(); // returns 0
    for (int i = 0; i <= groupCount; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%d. %s%n", i, matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

The parentheses do capture. As you can see, if we do

```
matcher.replaceAll("cold")
```

it will return "cold diggity dog"

I would expect (?i:hot) to be equivalent to ((?i)hot), but it is not. The latter case is a capture group.

This is not a duplicate of [Java RegEx Matcher.groupCount returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413974/java-regex-matcher-groupcount-returns-0) because in that question, there truly were no capture groups, so the groupCount correctly returns 0. However in my case, this should indeed be considered a capture group because it indeed performs a capture!

Comment: I don't think it's a capturing group - rather, I think the syntax `(?i` means to interpret the part inside as a *non-capturing group* with the `i` flag. The characters *are* consumed, but not captured, pehaps https://regex101.com/r/1yCnzv/1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java RegEx Matcher.groupCount returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413974/java-regex-matcher-groupcount-returns-0)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that. In that case, no capture groups were specified, so the groupCount is correctly returning 0. In mine, the pattern is capturing characters from the expression.

Comment: `replaceAll()` changing the text doesn't mean that's a capture group in your RE; it just means that the regular expression matched part of the string you tested it on. You'd see this if you changed the replacement text to something like `"($1)"`.

Comment: @Shawn yes, that is correct. The question is why? It is contained inside parentheses, it captures text, so why is it not a capture group. I would think (?i:hot) should be exactly equivalent to ((?i)hot), but it is not. The latter is indeed a capture group

Comment: It's not a capture group. The first commenter is correct. Refer to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Agreed. It is not. But why is it not?? And the first commenter flagged this as a possible duplicate, which it is not

Comment: It's not because `(?:blah)` is the syntax for a non-capturing group. **read the documentation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `?i:`. This is not a hint to ignore case but is a syntax for the non-capturing group. One use case I found for its use is to use (?i) in the middle of the regex for ignoring case match of back-reference `\1`. Below is a modified version of your program using it

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)(\\W+(?i:\\1)\\b)+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Hello hello");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int groupCount = matcher.groupCount(); // returns 0
        for (int i = 0; i <= groupCount; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d. %s%n", i, matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not a lookahead or behind. It is a hint to the regex processor to ignore case inside this "capture group" (or whatever you want to call it)

Comment: Then why does it ignore case? ?i does not compile (?i hot). You have to enclose it in parens ((?i)hot). Why?

Comment: If you remove the bit about look aheads, I will check you up

Comment: @VictorGrazi Check the source code of `Pattern.class` line 2048 and 2894. Based on that it clear that if pattern starts with `(?` and doesn't have following character as `:=!><$@` then it goes to `default` section and checks second consecutive character must be `)` or `:` or else throw error. So what shawn has said is right `(?...)` is a syntax for non-capturing group.

Comment: Great use case and a great tip! Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's right in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special):

> (?idmsux-idmsux:*X*)  *X*, as a **non-capturing group** with the given flags i d m s u x on - off

If you want a capturing group, just wrap it in another set of parentheses:

```
((?i:hot))
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL; DR

> I would expect `(?i:hot)` to be equivalent to `((?i)hot)`, but it is not. The latter case is a capture group.

Almost all regex engines turn off an inline modifier as soon as a closing parenthesis at the same level is seen. So both above are equivalent except the capturing part.

First syntax is totally something else.

### Mode-modified span

Parentheses aren't supposed to mean a capturing group or a non-capturing group but they could bring a different feature into the usage which may capture or not. All opening parentheses that immediately follow a question mark have a special meaning for regex engines:

```
(?...)
```

Flag `i` is a *modifier*. Modifiers could be enabled out of the regex context but some regex engines support a syntax for *inline modifiers* which provides you an ability to enable them within the regex itself. Hence the word *inline*:

```
(?i)test(?-i)
 ^        ^
 E        D
```

On the other hand there is another similar syntax known as *mode-modified span*: `(?modifiers:...)` which *resembles* a non-capturing group `(?:...)` that has some modifiers between `?` and `:` and applies them **only** to the subexpression enclosed:

```
(?i:test)
```

Having that said, both `(?i)test(?-i)` and `(?i:test)` are equal. This feature is supposed to enable / disable modifiers. Period.

We don't expect more functionality from it.